# How to show the result of this jQuery function without the need of clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function below, however I want to make it work on windows load and show the result without clicking the button.
This is the code I use https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SuyashMShepHertz/indexedDB_sample/master/index.html

How to do this?

```
$("#getBtn").click(function(){
  var type = 'permanent';
  var request = db.transaction(["hashes"],"readwrite").objectStore("hashes").get(type);
  request.onsuccess = function(event){
    $("#result").html("Name : "+request.result.name);    
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just put it in `$(document).ready`, like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var type = 'permanent';
   var request = db.transaction(["hashes"],"readwrite").objectStore("hashes").get(type);
   request.onsuccess = function(event){
      $("#result").html("Name : "+request.result.name);    
   };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however i get this in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined`. This is the raw code I am using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SuyashMShepHertz/indexedDB_sample/master/index.html

Answer (score 0):

just put your code in

```
 $( window ).load(function() {
       //Code Here
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need it both on click and initially when the page loads, make it a reusable function:

```
function doTheThing() {
    var type = 'permanent';
    var request = db.transaction(["hashes"], "readwrite").objectStore("hashes").get(type);
    request.onsuccess = function(event) {
        $("#result").html("Name : " + request.result.name);
    };
}
```

Then call it from both places you need it:

- On page load
- On click

To call it on page load, just make sure your script is at the end of the HTML (just before the closing `</body>` tag; this is [best practice](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom) unless you have a good reason for doing something else) and call it:

```
doTheThing();
```

If you can't put the script at the end of the HTML, you can use jQuery's `ready` callback instead:

```
// Concise, but easy to misunderstand:
$(doTheThing);

// Or more verbose but also more clear:
$(document).ready(doTheThing);
```

(See note below about doing it directly or indirectly.)

To call it on click, hook it up, either directly or indirectly:

```
// Directly
$("#getBtn").click(doTheThing);

// Or indirectly
$("#getBtn").click(function() {
    doTheThing();
});
```

The only reason for hooking it up indirectly would be to avoid having it receive the event object jQuery will pass it automatically, and to avoid having its return value examined by jQuery to see if it should stop propagation and prevent the default event action.

To avoid creating globals, I'd make sure the entire thing is in a scoping function:

```
(function() {
    function doTheThing() {
        var type = 'permanent';
        var request = db.transaction(["hashes"], "readwrite").objectStore("hashes").get(type);
        request.onsuccess = function(event) {
            $("#result").html("Name : " + request.result.name);
        };
    }

    doTheThing();

    $("#getBtn").click(doTheThing);
})();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however i get this in console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transaction' of undefined`. This is the raw code I am using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SuyashMShepHertz/indexedDB_sample/master/index.html

Comment: @Xalloumokkelos: Just make sure the script is **after** whatever script it is that defines your `db` object. (Or if that script runs asynchronously, it'll provide a callback, and you'd use that callback to run the function initially.)